# Renaming large amount of files

Tags: bash, file, batch-file, rename

i need a script which will rename large amount of files. I got a folder with a lot of files. Every file is named by ID. Then i have a CSV file like this:

> oldID;newID
>
> oldID;newID
>
> etc...

Every old and new id is specific and original. I'd like to ask what should be the best way to do it or little help in bash/batch.

Comment: Does your comma separated values (CSV) file separate values by semicolon?

Comment: Is it bash or batch? Bash is used by Linux and Batch is used by Windows.

Comment: it is exactly as i wrote. Every line == two numbers separated by semicolon.

For this project, I prefer batch.

Thanks!

Comment: I just posted an answer for **bash** then now read your desire for a **batch** version.  Please be specific in your questions about what you want and use the appropriate tags.  (If you use the [tag:bash] tag, you will get people who want to answer bash questions.)

Comment: You prefer batch but you accepted the bash answer? Make up your mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **bash** (the shell used in world of Linux, UNIX, etc.), you can use the following short script based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/918931#918931) internal field separator answer.  This assumes that you are using a semicolon (`;`) as the delimiter of your "CSV" file and that there is only one such delimiter.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=';' read -ra names; do
    mv "${names[0]}" "${names[1]}";
done < translation.csv
```

where `translation.csv` is your file containing the name translations with an `oldname;newname` format.

If you are instead asking for a **batch** file (i.e. for Windows, DOS, etc.) then that is a different animal in a different world.

Answer (score 4):

The solution for batch is very similar to e0k's solution for bash; you read the file in one line at a time, split the line on semicolons, and rename the file accordingly.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in (ids.csv) do ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

This assumes that your IDs are in a file called ids.csv

Comment: Why not use `ren "%%A" "%%B"`?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your OS is some unix (like linux), and given that the use of csv files has been your own choice, there might be an easier way to go: mmv can rename many files in one go, using patterns to match original files, and allowing to use the matched strings in the target file names.  See http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html.